# List of maven(3.1.0) clover plugin properties/goals

Tags: maven, clover

I can't seem to find the list of goals for maven 3.1.0. I was able to find a list for maven-1.x here - http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/clover/properties.html

But where's the list for the new version?

Minor question, the term goal in maven is when you call a command like **mvn clover:optimize**, correct? (Just want to make sure I'm using the right term)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [help:describe](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/describe-mojo.html) to print the documentation for a plugin to the console.

Comment: Works for me. To be specific, the command is mvn help:describe -Dplugin=clover2

Answer (score 0):

The latest documentation of the Clover Plugin for Maven 2.x/3.x is here:

- https://docs.atlassian.com/maven-clover2-plugin/latest

PS: I guess you've been looking for a wrong plugin. Please note that the Clover plugin for Maven 2.x and 3.x is named 'maven-clover2-plugin'. The 'maven-clover-plugin' is for Maven 1.x.